# How can I send 'ListBox selected item`s value' to LocalDatabase - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a listbox like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstBoxBaseUnitOfMeasure" Width="100" Margin="0,4,0,0">
     <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
          <TextBlock Text="EACH" Height="30"/>
          <TextBlock Text="GRAM" Height="30"/>
     </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I would like to send selected item to Local Database  like this:

```
private void AddProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TblProductsToOrder newProductToOrder = new TblProductsToOrder
            {
                OrderNId = selectedID,
                Quantity = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text),
                **BaseUnitOfMeasure = ??????????????**
            };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `BaseUnitOfMeasure` property is of type `String`, you can try this way :

```
String selectedUnit = "";
if(lstBoxBaseUnitOfMeasure.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var selectedTextBlock = (TextBlock)lstBoxBaseUnitOfMeasure.SelectedItem;
    selectedUnit = selectedTextBlock.Text;
}
TblProductsToOrder newProductToOrder = new TblProductsToOrder
                                        {
                                            OrderNId = selectedID,
                                            Quantity = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text),
                                            BaseUnitOfMeasure = selectedUnit
                                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

ListPicker fires an event,SelectionChanged whenever a item is selected. You will need to listen to that event

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstBoxBaseUnitOfMeasure" Width="100" Margin="0,4,0,0" SelectionChanged="listPicker_SelectionChanged">
     <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
          <TextBlock Text="EACH" Height="30"/>
          <TextBlock Text="GRAM" Height="30"/>
     </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
</toolkit:ListPicker>


 private void listPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstBoxBaseUnitOfMeasure.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var texBlock = (TextBlock) lstBoxBaseUnitOfMeasure.SelectedItem;
                selectedUnit = texBlock.Text;
                TblProductsToOrder newProductToOrder = new TblProductsToOrder
                    {
                        OrderNId = selectedID,
                        Quantity = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text),
                        BaseUnitOfMeasure = selectedUnit
                    };
            }
        }
```